# How do I write a simple if-elseif protocol in Latex?

Tags: tabularx, algorithms

I've tried using algorithm, algorithmic, etc.. but I can't seem to find what I need. I want something similar to this:

[image]

This is the closest I got using tcolorbox and align:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,
                    colback=white,
                    coltitle=black,  
                    fonttitle=\normalfont,
                    adjusted title= \underline{\textbf{Protocol $\hat{Q_1}$}} (for undecided process $i$ at time $m$):]
    \begin{align*}
        &\textbf{if} \quad K_i good(\exists 0) &\textbf{then} \quad decide_i(0) \\
        &\textbf{elseif} \quad  m=t+1 \cup same_i(m,m-1) &\textbf{then} \quad decide_i(1)
    \end{align*}


\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

I would like to get rid of the extra space between the title and the code, as well as make everything align as in the example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how general this is.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\fun}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{3em}}>{\bfseries}ll>{\bfseries}ll@{}}
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{%
  \underline{\textbf{Protocol $\hat{Q_1}$}} (for undecided process $i$ at time $m$):%
} \\[2ex]
if     & $K_i \fun{good}(\exists 0)$      & then & $\fun{decide}_i(0)$ \\
elseif & $m=t+1 \cup \fun{same}_i(m,m-1)$ & then & $\fun{decide}_i(1)$ \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the `tcolorbox` you could use `tabularx` instead of the `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,
                    colback=white,
                    coltitle=black,  
                    fonttitle=\normalfont,
                    adjusted title= \underline{\textbf{Protocol $\hat{Q_1}$}} (for undecided process $i$ at time $m$):]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXll}
        \textbf{if} & $K_i good(\exists 0)$ &\textbf{then} & $\text{decide}_i(0)$ \\
        \textbf{elseif} &  $m=t+1 \cup \text{same}_i(m,m-1)$ &\textbf{then} & $\text{decide}_i(1)$
    \end{tabularx}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you might want to have a look into the packages designed for pseudocode such as `algorithm2e`, `algorithmicx`, `algorithm`, `algpseudocode`...